# Apex: PageMessage alignment is not proper

Tags: apex, visualforce

The "Error" should be right beside  the text but it is coming in center . How to resolve it . Or how can i override this message block ?? Pls help
 [image]

Comment: We'd love to help you, but I think it'd probably be more useful if you could include a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable)](http://sscce.org/), Example so we can either test or replicate the challenge you're facing. I'm not sure we'll be able to help you without some code samples. Also see How to Ask for more information on [how to write a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks but i sorted it out

Comment: Glad you found the solution. You can post your answer with relevant details for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to take  tag in a div tag and then set the text:alignment : left or right in style tag .

example :

```
<div style ="text-alignment:left ; left-padding- 10px">

  `<apex:pageMessages>`</div>`
```